# Second and third Kaplan Meier plots exceeding set x limit

Tags: r, plot, survival-analysis

[image]

As you can see from the picture above, the second and third Kaplan Meier curves exceed the x-limit and box that I set.

I used the exact same code for all three plots, changing only the actual survival object each time, as well as the y-axis labels and ranges.  The x-limit and labels were the same for every plot.  An example of the code is below:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))

surv.obj <- survfit(Surv(Start, Stop, Event) ~ factor(Characteristic),
    data=dataset)

par( mai=c(2,3,1.5,0.42) )

colours <- c("gray0", "gray75")


# x-axis
max( unlist(unname(summary(surv.obj)["time"] )) ) # 1274 


plot(surv.obj, mark.time=F, col=colours, lty=1, lwd=2, yscale=100,
xscale=1,
fun="event",

ylab="",
xlab="Follow-Up (days)",
xlim=c(0, 1280),
xaxt="n",

axes=F,
cex.lab=1.8,
cex.main=1.8
)

box("plot", lty=1)

axis(2, cex.axis=1.5, at=c(0, 0.04, 0.08, 0.12, 0.16) )
axis(1, cex.axis=1.5, at=c(0, 300, 600, 900, 1200) )
```

with this repeated another two times for the next two curves.

I know it is not the 'plot specific' code that is the issue, because when I plot each one separately (and ignore par(mfrow=c(2,2))) they are produced the way I want them to be (with the survival curve cut-off at approx 1280 days).  Also, I tried plotting only the second and third plots using par(mfrow=c(1,2)) and the first one turned out fine (which is the second one in the plot in the picture) and the second one again exceeded the box.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Thanks
Vicki

Comment: What does `par("xpd")` return?

Comment: is there any chance you could post `dput(dataset)`?  (or even `dput(dataset[, c("Start", "Stop", "Event", "Characteristic")])`)?

Comment: Look at `?plot.survfit`. It's got some different parameters. The limits are set with xmax. Apparently there is a side-effect where xlim works only for the first plot.

Comment: Thanks, setting the limit with xmax=1280 worked perfectly!